# How can I know my layout's total height and width in Android Studio layout editor?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am designing a layout for a Notification with Custom `View` using Android Studio Layout Editor and Text. But according to the Android Developer site there is a caution to this given as:

> **Caution:** When you use a custom notification layout, take special care to ensure that your custom layout works with different device orientations and resolutions. While this advice applies to all UI layouts, it's especially important for notifications because the space in the notification drawer is very restricted. The height available for a custom notification layout depends on the notification view. Usually, collapsed view layouts are limited to 64 dp, and expanded view layouts are limited to 256 dp.

And can be found in  [this link in the developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification.html). So for my layout to look good in all devices it should be around 64dp for collapsed and 256dp for expanded views.

So the question is how will I know the total height of the `Layout` given all my `TextView`s are single line and ellipsized `end` using Android Studio layout editor? What is a workaround to calculate the paddings, margins, textsizes, view sizes and give the whole height of a layout? And if it is NOT possible in Android Studio layout editor what is a alternative to avoid adjust and run, adjust and run, adjust and run...?

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamic get the screen size inside the code and get, change and save back to the view's layoutparams if you require fully control.

Better approach in Android studio is you design the layout xml specific for each screen config, such as added a directory of layout named  layout-xlarge for large device, also you can build a value-xlarge directory and added a dimens.xml file and set various value (for example    40dp) for different config, and get it inside the layout.xml  (@dimen/dimenxxxsize).

please reference of below:   https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html